# How to oAuth with Facebook4j on Android

Tags: android, facebook

Is there a way to Login  with user and password into Facebook API with Facebook4j library on Android?

I did some research, but anything clear appears:

-Some projects using a WebView to take authoritation just chrash or don't work properly.

-Using Facebook class on Facebook4j its imposible to take the access token, at least with codes i found.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. It really works, and makes all the job easier:

[ASNE library](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE)

You can login on Facebook (using the official SDK) and post/retrieve some information about posts, friends, bio... It's just enough for a big chunk of apps.

Thank you ccreedon1 for your help man!

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want to make direct calls to facebook Graph API without the third party API then you need to get

appID: create an app on developers.facebook.com for what ever purpose you need android website etc..

user access token: go to the Graph API on developers.facebook.com, select your app and click get the user access token, ensure you give the app the permissions it need in the checkboxes

use the appid, appsecret and the access token to make the post call, if you want to keep the info and post at a later time you  will need a longlife/permanant token which you can retrieve with the userID and the accesstoken

Post to feed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post

That is how I have done this but probably the more recommended way is to use the official Facebook Android SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

hope that helps!

Comment: I want access to user post comments, like posts and share on his timeline.

Comment: I tried the Facebook SDK examples, but still not working those ones. Could be an API problem?

Comment: do you have the app and its permissions set up correctly?

Comment: yes, totally (internet and write external storage for this "HelloFacebookSample")

Comment: try using direct http calls